# How to make absolute positioned element overflow out of its relative container

Tags: html, css

Imagine I have the following structure in the body

```
<div class='green-wrapper'>
    <div class='rel-parent'>
        <div class='notification'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The styles in general are like this

```
.rel-parent {
  background: blue;
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
  width: 250px;
}

.notification {
  background: red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 10px);
  right: -10px;
}

.green-wrapper {
  background: green;
  padding: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 290px;

  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: visible;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* reset */
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

The notification is absolutely positioned and it is supposed to stay on the edge of the greeen-wraper. The thing is that if the green-wrapper width is limited I cannot make the notification icon just overflow. It is really tiny thing and creating scroller for it is definitely not what I look for.

Here is an example [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/yohemihaci/edit?html,css,output), notice the scroller at the bottom. Is there a general way to get rid of it? I thought putting overflow: visible on the green container should do the fix, but to no avail.

Comment: Declaring `overflow: visible` on `.green-wrapper` does work - tried and tested.

Comment: overflow-x: hidden; instead of visible